# updating an image with same name

Tags: git, version-control

I am using Git.

I have changed what an image looks like and saved it out as the same name as what was previously there. I replaced the image in my directory. I can see the image thumbnail has changed and when I open it is the new image. However, when I view the site it still shows the old image. When I ran gitk --all it said there was a diff. I have committed it and did a git add thinking that would fix it. I have obviously cleared my cache many times. Another person who fetched from me has the exact same issue. They see the new image in their directory but the old image is being displayed in the web browser.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to append "?timestamp" to the src attribute of the img tag.

Example:

```
<image src="some_image.jpg?123456789" />
```

You have to use server-side logic to get the File modification time (File mtime) and convert that to seconds since last Unix epoch.

Another option is to use versions instead of timestamps.

Examples:

- first revision

  ```
  <image src="some_image.jpg?v=1" />
  ```
- second revision

  ```
  <image src="some_image.jpg?v=2" />
  ```

Comment: Teddy...so your saying it is a cache issue? I'm not seeing how that could be since it is happening on browsers that haven't viewed the page before.

Comment: Thank you @Teddy. I was facing the same issue sometimes, and your solution shows me a simple way to solve it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What you see  in the directory / working copy is what you should see on your web browser. Git will not do some magic and make your site serve a older version of the image.

You haven't provided the info on how your site is actually deployed. Is is a local deploy where you are just having a working directory on your machine and the site is deployed from this? Or you deploy to a remote server from your local directory? Or do you push to a remote server and the site is served from that remote server? If it is the latter, make sure the change in the image is pushed to the server.

When your colleague pulled the changes from you and saw the browser, how are they seeing the site again? Is it being deployed on their box again, or from the server? If it is the latter, of course, the pulling wouldn't have changes the contents on the server right?

Can you answer these questions and add the details to your question.